# How to compile assets on Heroku with Webpack Encore?

Tags: symfony, heroku, npm, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

I added a the heroku/nodejs buildpack to my Symfony heroku app, and I am able to install my yarn dependencies.

However I am not able to run

```
$ yarn run encore production
```

I always have the same error `Command "encore" not found` whether I run the command in composer.json :

```
// composer.json
 "compile": [
     "node_modules/.bin/encore production",
     [•••]
```

or in package.json

```
//package.json

  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild" : "yarn run encore production"
    [•••]
```

Comment: I finally fixed it. My mistake was to follow the Webpack Encore documentation that recommend to install Webpack Encore only for dev dependencies. I guess that it's not relevant in a heroku context (?). I installed all my yarn dependencies in `"dependencies"` instead of `"devDependencies"` in package.json and it works !

Answer (score 5):

In your package.json root file :

> ```
> "scripts": {
>     ...
>     "heroku-postbuild" : "node_modules/.bin/encore production"
> }
> ```
>
> It will run your webpack encore and running your others npm modules.

Comment: This helped me a lot. `"heroku-postbuild" : "encore production"` is enough by the way.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming here, you'll first need to add the node buildpack to your app, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086897/deploy-php-project-with-yarn-to-heroku).

Make sure to add the node buildpack **before** the php one.

Then, add `"node_modules/.bin/encore production"` to your compile (as shown in the question).

Finally, as written in comment, don't forget to change webpack dependencies from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I always run Encore commands as `cd my-project/ && ./node_modules/.bin/encore ...` Would that work for you?