# Deploy PHP project with Yarn to Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, web-deployment, yarnpkg, heroku-cli

Locally I simply run `composer install` and `yarn install`, but when pushing to Heroku only composer dependencies get installed, but not Yarn components. I can't seem to find a way for Heroku to trigger Yarn components installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to add the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack inside Heroku application's settings page, alongside the already present `heroku/php`. The next deploy then also installed the yarn components.